# Adicionar tabela com AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Bom dia preciso de ajuda nesse script. Que ao selecionar uma opção no select seja colocado dinamicamente dados na tabela. Mas não sei como retornar as Tags html para a página origem. Na página salvar.php será feito todo um tratamento com banco de dados e assim gerar a tabela com as tarefas referentes a cada funcionario.

Espero que tenha sido claro. Obrigado desde já

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select#funcBusca')
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  $(function() {
    
    $('#funcBusca').click(function(e) {

     
      e.preventDefault();

      
      var id = $('#funcBusca').val();

      
      $.post('salvar.php', {
        id: id
      }, function(resposta) {
        
        if (resposta == 1) {
          alert(OK)
        } else {
          alert(resposta);
        }
      });

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Por Funcionário:
<select name="filtro_func" onchange="" id="funcBusca">
  <option value="0">Todos</option>
  <option value="1">Fulano</option>
  <option value="0">Ciclano</option>
  <option value="1">Beltrano</option>

</select>
<section id="secao">
  <p class="title" data-section-title>
    <a href="#">Tarefas Cadastradas</a>
  </p>
  <div class="content" data-section-content>
    <table class="responsive" width="100%" id="tarefas_cadastradas">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="15%">A Tarefa</th>
          <th width="15%">Funcionário</th>
          <th width="15%">Setor</th>
          <th width="5%">Status</th>
          <th width="10%" style="text-align:center;">Prazo</th>
          <th width="10%">Nível Urgência</th>
          <th width="10%">Dia Fechamento</th>
          <th width="7%" style="text-align:center;">Editar</th>
          <th width="7%" style="text-align:center;">Excluir</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!--colocar linhas aqui -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer adicionar o conteúdo retornado pela requisição Ajax na tabela. Como vi que você está usando jquery na página fiz alguns ajustes na criação do evento usando ele. Coloquei um exemplo de como adicionar os dados da resposta na tabela.

```
$("#funcBusca").on("change", function() {
    var id = $('#funcBusca').val();

     $.post('salvar.php', 
           {id: id}, 
           function(resposta) {
                var html = '<tr>'
                             +'<td>Tarefa 1</td>'
                             +'<td>Funcionário 1</td>'
                             +'<td>Setor 1</td>'
                             +'<td>Status 1</td>'
                             +'<td>Prazo 1</td>'
                             +'<td>Nível Urgência 1</td>'
                             +'<td>Dia Fechamento</td>'
                             +'<td>1</td>'
                             +'<td>1</td>';
                          +'</tr>';                 

                //adicionar o conteúodo no tbody
                $("#tarefas_cadastradas tbody").html(html);                             
           }
    );

});
```